# Django Elasticsearch AWS httplib UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, utf-8, httplib

I'm trying to setup Elasticsearch with Django (without Haystack).
Everything works perfectly locally.
But when I try to use the [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)  client with IAM based authentication on AWS I get this error :

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 827, in _send_output
msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position132: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to use [aws-es-connection](https://github.com/elelsee/aws-es-connection) and [requests-aws4auth](https://github.com/sam-washington/requests-aws4auth) but I get the same error.

It only works when I allow open access on AWS and use only elasticsearch-py like so

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
ES_CLIENT = Elasticsearch(
    ['search-domain-xxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
```

But I want something more secure ... 
I think it is a utf-8/unicode/str problem but I can't manage to resolve it :(

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, and the code that triggers it?

Answer (score 3):

I finally manage to fix the bug by using a custom serializer :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection, serializer, compat, exceptions

class JSONSerializerPython2(serializer.JSONSerializer):
"""Override elasticsearch library serializer to ensure it encodes utf characters during json dump.
See original at: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/serializer.py#L42
A description of how ensure_ascii encodes unicode characters to ensure they can be sent across the wire
as ascii can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage
"""
def dumps(self, data):
    # don't serialize strings
    if isinstance(data, compat.string_types):
        return data
    try:
        return json.dumps(data, default=self.default, ensure_ascii=True)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        raise exceptions.SerializationError(data, e)
```

and then pass the serializer to elasticsearch

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(..., serializer=JSONSerializerPython2())
```

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/374)

Answer (score 1):

If someone can find the reason behind this error, I would be immensely grateful. Things I have tried with no luck:

- encode things to 'utf-8' before writing (result: no errors thrown, es index not even created)
- something like the code-snippet below (result: no errors thrown, es index not even created)

  ```
  def convert_unicode_to_str(item):
      if isinstance(item, basestring):
          return str(item)
      .....
      .....
  ```

***[Note: This is a bit of a hack, but it gets the job done]***

So, `sys.setdefaultencoding(..)` is not available in the [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) module's namespace. This is solved by calling the reload function on `sys`.

Now, prior to writing to ES, setting the default encoding to *'utf-8'* solves this problem. Just to be sure that nothing else breaks as a result of this, I think it is a good idea to reset the default encoding to what it was before the switch.

```
reload(sys)

# keep track of what the old encoding was
old_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()

# set the default encoding to `itf-8`
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

#################
## write to es ##
#################

# reset the state of the world to what it was
sys.setdefaultencoding(old_encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

extending Debosmit Ray's solution for django-haystack.

add to search_indexes:

```
def set_default_utf8(method):
    """
    Set utf-8 as default encoding, perform `method`,
    then set the old encoding back.
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        reload(sys)
        old_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
        sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

        result = method(*args, **kwargs)

        sys.setdefaultencoding(old_encoding)
        return result
    return wrapper


class EntryIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    ...

    @set_default_utf8
    def update(self, using=None):
        """Overrides entire index update to use UTF-8."""
        super(StreamEntryIndex, self).update(using)

    @set_default_utf8
    def update_object(self, instance, using=None, **kwargs):
        """Overrides index update for a single object using UTF-8."""
        super(StreamEntryIndex, self).update_object(instance, using, **kwargs)
```